# AlarmManager never start my Service

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

In my application, I am trying to start a service using `AlarmManager`. 
The code for `AlarmManager` is below:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

        ...

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5*1000, 5*1000, pintent);
        }

        ...
}
```

below is the Service Class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService.onStartCommand()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.max.android.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.max.android.myapp.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.max.android.myapp.SubsService" />
</manifest>
```

running `adb shell dumpsys alarm` I can see my alarm:

```
  RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{41878860 type 0 com.max.android.myapp}

    type=0 when=+3s954ms repeatInterval=5000 count=1

    operation=PendingIntent{41878850: PendingIntentRecord{41878760 com.max.android.myapp startService}}
```

But `MyService` is never started. Why is this not working?

Comment: I would expect some sort of a clue in the `adb logcat` output.

Comment: Bingo! `W/ActivityManager( 1506): Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.max.android.myapp/.SubsService (has extras) }: not found` any suggestion?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier thanks for your help.... I haven't seen this logcat entry in eclipse logcat viewer... the problem was in Android Manifest as pointed in [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570743/unable-to-start-service-intent-error-when-starting-service-from-an-activity-in)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. After looking at `adb logcat` I've found this warning: `W/ActivityManager( 1506): Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.max.android.myapp/.SubsService (has extras) }: not found` In AndroidManifest.xml, I had the < service> declaration after < application> instead of nested inside it.

Comment: I see that now. I suspected you hadn't included the service, but read your manifest too quicklyquickly to see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

[SystemClock.elapsedRealtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29)

> Returns milliseconds since boot, including time spent in sleep.

You can get current time in milliseconds by calling

```
new Date().getTime()
```

see https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: The alarm is scheduled correctly: `type=0 when=+3s954ms repeatInterval=5000 count=1` I think the problem is not here