# Awareness API not available in Android Wear 2.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-awareness, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to use the Awareness Fence API on Android Wear 2.0 but unable to do so.

When I setup the GoogleApiClient with Awareness.API and call connect(), I get these errors in logcat.

```
02-17 04:17:55.215 495-30247/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.contextmanager.service.ContextManagerService.START pkg=com.google.android.gms } U=0: not found
02-17 04:17:55.216 495-2552/? W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@9d06352
E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.contextmanager.service.ContextManagerService.START on com.google.android.gms
```

It's a Huawei watch with Android Wear 2.0 DP5, and GMS 10.2.0. Tried to search but came up with nothing, mostly just news about both of them together. Admittedly, haven't tried this on the phone yet.

I have been using the LocationService API from GMS successfully on the watch so I know at least the credentials/API key is set up properly for it, and I'm using a different instance of the GoogleApiClient than the one I use for LocationServices.

Anybody have any experience with this and know if it's not supported yet?

Thanks

Comment: Well, one reason of the error `"Unable to start service Intent"` is an error in AndroidManifest, the service must be included in the Manifest and the declaration of it must be correct. Check these SO question [4570743](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570743) and [3439356](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439356/unable-to-start-service-intent) for more information.

Comment: @KENdi Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately adding ```com.google.android.lms.service.ContextManagerService``` to the manifest didn't work :( Decompiled the Awareness API aar and no service with that name.

Comment: @AfzalivE, any progress with this? I'm finding the same issue

Comment: Nope, sorry. I left that company lol.