# Why isn't my ON_BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver working?

Tags: android

Trying to reset a SharedPreference every time the device is rebooted.

Here's my code:

**MyReceiver.java**

```
   package ***************;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mPrefs  = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0); 
        setStatus("***********");


    }

     public void setStatus(String statustext) {

         SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
         edit.putString("status", statustext);
         edit.commit();
      }

}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:versionCode="1" package="*********" android:versionName="1.8.3">
                  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <activity android:name=".Main"
                          android:label="@string/app_name"
                          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"                                 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                         <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <activity android:name="help"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MyReceiver"></activity>
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">

                <intent-filter> 
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETE"/> 
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
                </intent-filter> 
  </receiver>
</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

The SharedPreferences are setup in my Main activity. My goal is to get the ON_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast to trigger the MyReceiver activity, which resets a specific sharedPreference, however, when I try this, the SharedPref is not reset.

What am I doing wrong? (I incorporated both @Commonware and @Blundell's fixes, but it is still not working)

Comment: You can get rid of the <activity> tag for MyReceiver, as I assume it is unused anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not retrieving your shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
```

Does nothing. You'd need:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mPrefs  = context.getSharedPreferences(); // or if your not using the default  getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)
    setStatus("****************");


}
```

Comment: Exactly... it in fact should be crashing with a NPE. Good catch :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately, I implemented those changes and it still doesn't work. I will update my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `<receiver>` element outside of the `<application>` element, which will be ignored.

Comment: Just tested it... still doesn't work. I will update my original post with your changes.

Comment: Done the exact same thing myself :-) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439356/unable-to-start-service-intent/5439157#5439157