# start a service from an activity and bind it to another activity

Tags: java, android, background-service

I'm fetching data from a backend server using a **Service** which I started from **Activity A** and when the right data comes in, I start an **Activity B** from within the service.

My question is : Is it possible **to start** the service from **Activty A** and then when **Activity B** is running **bind** the service it  to use callback methodes from the service and when Activity is in background unbind the Service 
and keep it running?

Comment: very much possible, services are independent components.

Comment: so i just call the startService from the first activity and bind it to the second Activity there is no special approach ???

Comment: Yes, see [Android Service bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819368/android-service-can-be-bind-without-start) and [Calling activity class method from Service class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586031/calling-activity-class-method-from-service-class)