# Does bindService also call the onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, service, bindservice

Can i call bindService without calling startService? If so, does it also call my onCreate method in my Service?

```
  public static void bindMusicService(Context c){
        /*mediaPlayerServiceIntent binds our connection to the MediaPlayerService. */
        mediaPlayerServiceIntent = new Intent(c, MediaPlayerService.class);
        c.bindService(mediaPlayerServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mServiceIsBound = true;
        Log.i("Main","Service is bound!");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Service can be bind without start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819368/android-service-can-be-bind-without-start)