# Do i need to unbind service when i'm not calling startService?

Tags: java, android, service

On startup i call bindService in `onCreate()` of my first activity so i can access my mediaplayer object which is a static object.

```
public static void bindMusicService(Context c){
        /*mediaPlayerServiceIntent binds our connection to the MediaPlayerService. */
        mediaPlayerServiceIntent = new Intent(c, MediaPlayerService.class);
        c.bindService(mediaPlayerServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mServiceIsBound = true;
        Log.i("Main","Service is bound!");
}
```

Now when i click a song in my activity i call:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent);
```

But what if the user doesn't click on a song and just closed the app? Do i still need to call `unbindService();` in `onPause()`?

Because when the user does click on a song, it will show a notification which song is playing and when the app is moved to the background or swiped away and **unbind** is called, the notification won't work anymore.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819368/android-service-can-be-bind-without-start

Comment: you always have to call `unbindService` - otherwise you will get memory leak

Comment: @pskink but still want to be able to control my music playback when my app is destroyed, when my app is destroyed i show a notification of the song that was playing with previous/next song and if i unbind these buttons don't work anymore.

Comment: a notification? so most likely you use `android.app.Notification.Builder` - your service does not need to be bound when it wants to use a `Notification` and `NotificationManager`