# IntentService doesn't start from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am trying to start IntentService from BroadcastReceiver like ( in onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) function):

```
            Intent i = new Intent(context, RegService.class);
            i.putExtra("user_id", userId);
            i.putExtra("device_id", "bla");
            context.startService(i);
```

and RegService like

```
public class RegService extends IntentService {

    public RegService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public RegService(){
        super("RegService");    
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String c2dm_registration_id = intent
                .getStringExtra("c2dm_registration_id");
        String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
        String userId = intent.getStringExtra("user_id");
        String device_type = "android";
        try {

            JSONObject object = RestClient.sendC2DMRegistrationId(
                    c2dm_registration_id, device_type,
                    token, userId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

but I cannot enter in onHandle in RegService ( I passed through first code context.startService(i); but I cannot enter in onHandle, no message ). Did anybody have same experience and waht is a solution ?
I have in manifest

```
<service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".c2dm.RegService" />
```

Comment: I dont understand your question to well.  "like ( in onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) function):" where is this "onReceive" method your referring too?  Also the last paragraph, what does "i cannot enter in onHandle in RegService" mean?

Comment: also posting your manifest.xml might help a little, since i believe your service should be defined in there as well.

Comment: @owengerig inside BroadcastReceiver class inside method onReceive I am executing code with context.startService. I cannot enter means that program never reaches that point or function. But from code above you can see that you can expect to enter in that function.

Comment: dont know a specific answer but i belive the name needs to match what the intent is calling.  like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439356/unable-to-start-service-intent

Comment: I take it RegService is in the package: application_package.c2dm ?

Comment: i have copy pasted above code.Its working fine for me.

Comment: Hello Damir, Have you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

When my IntentService was declared with just its class name in the manifest,then I was not able to call it from the Broadcast Receiver.I then gave the full name like :

```
<service  android:name="com.abc.def.services.DummyService" />
```

This did the trick and I was able to invoke this IntentService from within the Broadcast Receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared the service in the manifest?

If so and it does not work try to set an action on the intent anyway, evenhough you won't use it.