# Unable to start service Intent: not found

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I've the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439356/unable-to-start-service-intent/19105337#19105337) but i can't understand whats wrong.

**My issue is:** Unable to start service Intent { act=.connections.MoodyService } U=0: not found

**EDIT**
**I've changed my package from connections to service in the source code, sorry for the confusion**

**My manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.moody"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.6.7 alpha" >

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.Menu_esq"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu_esq" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.MainView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_view" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.moody.LeftActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_left" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.moody.RightActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_right" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.UserDetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="fragments.TopicsPreview"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_copy_of_topics_preview" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="activities.Loading" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".service.MoodyService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/moody_service" >
    </service>
</application>
```

**service is the package and MoodyService is the class name**

**My service class**

```
public class MoodyService extends Service {

public MoodyService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private boolean isRunning = false;
Object getContent;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    // Announcement about starting
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting the Demo Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    // Start a Background thread
    isRunning = true;
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new BackgroundThread());
    backgroundThread.start();

    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Stop the Background thread
    isRunning = false;

    // Announcement about stopping
    Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping the Demo Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

private class BackgroundThread implements Runnable {
    int counter = 0;

    public void run() {
        try {
            counter = 0;
            while (isRunning) {
                System.out.println("" + counter++);
                new Contents().getAll(getResources(),
                        getApplicationContext());
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
            }

            System.out.println("Background Thread is finished.........");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**And in my main Intent.**

```
Intent start = new Intent(".service.MoodyService");
        this.startService(start);
```

**and also tried**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoodyService.class);
        this.startService(intent);
```

**and tried with the full path**

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.moody.service.MoodyService"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/moody_service" >
```

Comment: still there is some error howcome ur error in package 'act=com.example.moody.connections.MoodyService' but u are having `"com.example.moody.service.MoodyService"' as package name

Comment: @ShakeebS i've changed for a new package and forgot to update the post

Comment: I found this blog entry which explained the compileSdk 30 issue really well
https://asvid.github.io/2021-09-03-android-service-binding-on-api30

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Solved**

I deleted the period in the beginning of the package name in the manifest and it worked, in another words:

This doesn't work:

```
.yourPackage.YourClass
```

But this does work:

```
 yourPackage.YourClass
```

And in the main:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoodyService.class);
        this.startService(intent);
```

But it goes against what is written in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html):

> **android:name** The name of the Service subclass that implements the service. This should be a fully qualified class name (such as,
>   "com.example.project.RoomService"). However, as a shorthand, if the
>   first character of the name is a period (for example, ".RoomService"),
>   it is appended to the package name specified in the 
>   element. Once you publish your application, you should not change this
>   name (unless you've set android:exported="false").

There is no default. The name must be specified.

Comment: Comlpetely missed that, though it is an error on your part. When you have package="com.example.moody" in the root of your manifest and you write android:name=".service.MoodyService", then the system will look for a service called "com.example.moody.service.MoodyService". But your output at top of q says "com.example.moody.connections.MoodyService", hence a copy paste error at some time, I assume.

Comment: still there is some error howcome ur error in package 'act=com.example.moody.connections.MoodyService' but u  are having `"com.example.moody.service.MoodyService"' as package name

Comment: is because i've updated the packages in the code and edited the question, but forgot to update the package name in the question

Comment: the same happened to me when i renamed my Service class. Had to change it manually in the manifest

Comment: In my case this been reverse. I changed in my manifest from "yourPackage.YourClass" to ".yourPackage.YourClass" and it works. I realize that "." is a very big thing :) @firetrap Thanks for suggestion  :)

Comment: for me it was the exact opposite

Comment: also using $ instead of . in the name for the sub classes may not make it works

Answer (score 23):

The service must be also be included in the **Manifest**:

```
<service android:name="com.x.x.serviceclass"></service>
```

Comment: What about if this is in androidTest directory?  Does there need to be a separate Manifest there?

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to declare service that's why I faced this issue.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have declared your service in the manifest file.

```
<service  
      android:name=".MyService"  
      android:enabled="true" >
</service>
```

and try writing getApplicationContext() instead of "this" keyword

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MoodyService.class));
```

Comment: What's the `enabled` for?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you are using that package-like name for your service name, but why don't you use class name for starting the service?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
context.startService(intent);
```

Comment: I tried that no diference same error, what i've done:" Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoodyService.class);
   this.startService(intent); " and also changed to a new package but same result, it was only there because that package it's not used anymore

Comment: This is the exact problem that I was having.  AndroidManifest.xml was fine, but I was passing the intent received by the onReceive() in BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 3):

I think in manifest package name for service is wrong as you said your package name is  `connections` so it should be like this

```
  android:name ="connections.MoodyService"
```

or

```
  android:name="com.example.moody.connections.MoodyService"
```

to invoke service do

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoodyService.class);
    this.startService(intent);
```

Comment: Yes you're right as i mentioned in my own answer, but the docs say: "However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".RoomService"), it is appended to the package name specified in the element" so i've the period because service is the package

Comment: `connection` is package name or `service` is package name

Comment: i've updated the question, MoodyService.java was in the package - "connections", now it's in the package - "service", my error was not the package name i only forgot to update the question

Answer (score 1):

my service is in "service" package and my manifest service enrty like this;

```
     <service
        android:name="service.TimerService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an empty constructor in the service?

If not, try that.

Also uncertain if you can use the Intent like that. You could try the 'new Inten(this, MoodyService.class)' construction.

Comment: Yes i did, and also tried:                                          Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoodyService.class);
this.startService(intent); i've updated my question with the service code

Answer (score -4):

Did you try to use the android:name that you specified in the Manifest?

Android Manifest:

```
<service 
             android:enabled="true" 
             android:name="UploadService" />
```

The call would be sth like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("UploadService");
```