# Android Global Service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I want to launch a Service from an another application.

Logcat error is:

```
Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.oic.launchertest.service/.DataSyncService } U=0: not found
```

Manifest from the App with the Service

```
<service
    android:name="com.oic.launchertest.service.DataSyncService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
</service>
```

In the other App I want to launch the service with the following code

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent( new ComponentName("com.oic.launchertest.service", "com.oic.launchertest.service.DataSyncService"));
startService(intent);
```

I could need some advice, what could cause this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105587/unable-to-start-service-intent-not-found) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359786/android-unable-to-start-service-intent-not-found)

Comment: @DevendraSingh both of those threads did not help in my case

Comment: delete the service and re-create new one. or restart the studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the Problem with the following solution. I read this in a comment but can't find the thread anymore...

Changing the location of the service did help.

I changed it from

```
com.oic.launchertest.service.DataSyncService
```

to

```
com.oic.launchertest.launcher.DataSyncService
```

and the Service was found now. Maybe this was some android naming complication, because I had service in the package name? I have no clue.