# app appears in Manage Applications, but not on the main menu

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I'm using Eclipse to make an Android app. I've used it before and not had this problem. The console says everything installed ok, so I'm a little confused. I'm not sure what is relevant from logcat, but I can post it if you think that would help.

I've restarted Eclipse, ADB, the emulator, and the Mac several times in various orders and nothing has helped. I know it must be something simple but I haven't played around with this in a few months.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hyser.pinpoint"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</application>
<activity android:name=".pinpoint" android:label="pinpoint">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml? Your main activity needs to have the proper intent filter for it to show up in the application tray.

Comment: yeah, i'm definitely missing something there. i can't believe i forgot to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity needs to be inside of your application tag in your manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

<activity android:name=".pinpoint" android:label="pinpoint">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>
```

It's a similar issue to this:

[Unable to start Service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439356/unable-to-start-service-intent/5439157#5439157)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<activity>` tag needs to be in the `<application>` block.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your manifest does not refer to any activities? If you install an app with no activities in the manifest you will get this behavior.