# Android - How to start and stop my service on specifed time?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, time, alarmmanager

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to make a simple app with a service, and I have some problems when I try to start my service.  I'm using a built-in Android `TimePicker` for starting and ending time.

```
//Getting start time from timePicker
Time startTime = new Time(startTimePicker.getCurrentHour(), startTimePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
// Creating intent
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisClass.this, ServiceClass.class);
// Setting pendingIntent for alarmManager
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisClass.this, 0, intent, 0);
// Creating new AlarmManager
AlarmManager startAlarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
startAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

The error is given in the last line: "Unable to start service Intent ( flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.mainActivity/. ServiceClass (has extras) ); not found".
I don't know if this is important, but the `Intent` has a bundle with two arrays in it, though I didn't copy that part of the code.

Comment: Did you declare the ServiceClass activity in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error probably occurs because you didn't declare your service class in the manifest. Make sure it is declared correctly ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439157/797390) for example it's not declared in the `application` tag, so it causes this error)

Comment: No I don't think this is the error, because I have declared service class in my manifest. Here is how:

    <service android:name=".ServiceClass" />

Comment: It's working now, you were right. I had an spelling error and that is why my class wasn't declared. xD Thanks anyway.

Comment: Great :) Please mark the question as solved - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask