# Android 11: starting a service of another app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-11

First app has a service:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.app.service.MyService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_MY_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Another app starts a service of the first app using (3 possible methods):

1:

```
val i = Intent("com.example.app.START_MY_SERVICE").apply {
    setPackage("com.example.app")
}
startService(i)
```

2:

```
val i = Intent().apply {
    component = ComponentName("com.example.app", "com.example.app.service.MyService")
}
startService(i)
```

3:

```
val i = Intent().apply {
    setClassName("com.example.app", "com.example.app.service.MyService")
}
startService(i)
```

All these methods to start a service of another app work from 23 API (6 Android) to 29 API (10 Android)

On Android 11 (30 API) it doesn't work, a service doesn't start, no exception:

When using 2-3 methods, in Logcat it prints:

`W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.app.service/.service.MyService } U=0: not found`

For 1 method nothing happens at all, no message at Logcat

So how can we start a service of some app from another app on Android 11?

Comment: Did you add a `<queries>` element to your manifest, identifying the other app?

Comment: @CommonsWare it can be any app - Tasker, Automate and so on, not my app, I can't know. This is just and interface to start commands

Comment: "I can't know" -- pick one app. Add the `<queries>` element, identifying that app. Try your `startService()` call to start a service in that app. If it does not work, then you will need to do more research. If, on the other hand, it *does* work, then you know that [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) is the source of your difficulty. And then you will need to decide whether you can convince Google (and perhaps other app distributors) that your app has justifiable reasons for bypassing package visibility rules.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, it's related to package visibility, I guess apps like Automate and Tasker have `android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`, so it should work fine

Comment: but  `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission Permitted use includes device search, antivirus apps, file managers, and browsers. so what for other purpose I have to use?
I want to store some data in my app a if user use some product in app b so for that I started service. so How to know what happened in my app b ? How to notify into app A locally? I don't want to call web-services for that so why can't call service from app which has target api 30?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app that starts a service of another app must include the next declaration in manifest:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.anotherapp" />
</queries>
```

or

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />`

(apps like Automate and Tasker have this permission)

Thanks to CommonsWare [Android 11: starting a service of another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648647/android-11-starting-a-service-of-another-app#comment119573080_67648647)

Comment: but  `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission Permitted use includes device search, antivirus apps, file managers, and browsers. so what for other purpose I have to use?
I want to store some data in my app a if user use some product in app b so for that I started service. so How to know what happened in my app b ? How to notify into app A locally? I don't want to call web-services for that so why can't call service from app which has target api 30?

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking how to open exprnal app, when I can't get info is this app installed on phone or not. You can try to startActivity() and handle ActivityNotFoundException, if it's present, that mean that app is not installed on the phone or can't open links like this. And also there are intent flags which can also make ActivityNotFoundException in case intent starts browser or pick activity dialog: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER, FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_DEFAULT

Here is more official and other info on this case:

Open external apps in Android:

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents

Tells when we can use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/517132/startactivity-throws-error-in-android-11-api-30.html

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/trusteer-mobile-sdk/5.3?topic=android-step-1-modify-app-manifest-androidmanifestxml

https://pretagteam.com/question/android-11-sdk-30-launch-external-app-doesnt-work

https://proandroiddev.com/the-quick-developers-guide-to-migrate-their-apps-to-android-11-e4ca2b011176